# A (not so) simple question!

Tags: visual, rebus

The question is ...

> CONNECT
>
> [image: 1]

Can you solve this one?! Hints will be provided after some time!

Comment: I am sorry, what has to be connected?

Comment: Presumably apple+van+half and Watson. Or, more precisely, something similar but with the *right* interpretations of those pictures rather than the first ones that come into one's head :-).

Comment: I'm confused by the fact the last symbol is not + but ~

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 3):

Gonna take a crack at it. Is it...

> Apple mobile app almost a supercomputer.

Firstly,

> The bitten apple logo representing **apple**.

Second image,

> The van refering to **mobile**

The 1/2

> And half could be half of one previous whole word. Take (about) half the letters away from apple and you get **app**

Final section,

> The lower photo seems to be a photo of the ibm super computer Watson and the wavy symbol infront represents **almost** or **approximate**.

Therefore,

> I believe the image is making reference to a mobile app being, or has been released for apple giving access to computations using Watson. Article about it [here](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=/amp/www.techrepublic.com/google-amp/article/ibm-watson-is-coming-to-the-iphone-and-thats-big-news-for-business-users/&ved=0ahUKEwjN98iboPXSAhXBx4MKHTTaAOoQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNHFVJY25gmmJ0WmXgsbd8kHcAke9g).

The final message is either

> **Apple mobile app similar to watson**

or

> **Apple mobile app almost a supercomputer**

Comment: How did you see ~ as "equivalent"?

Comment: @SIGSEGV Read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) on `~`

Comment: @SIGSEGV your right. The tilde ~ is supposed to mean approximate or almost. Only when the tilde is above an equal sign does it mean almost equal to. Updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to

> Connect your iPhone to IBM Watson.

First

> The Apple logo stands for "Apple".

Second

> The vehicle stands for "mobile".

Third

> The division (divide) stands for "device".

Put those together

> You get an Apple mobile device or an iPhone.

Last

> You have the connect symbol with IBM Watson.

Answer (score 0):

Lemme take a quick guess...

> From Apple mobile app to IBM Watson

Mostly, It's like AstroMax's answer, but I thought the ~ sign should be interpreted as 'from a to b' format, like 'a~b' can be interpreted as 'from a to b'.